# How to migrate SQL data to NoSQL document?

Tags: python, sql, django, migrate, nosql

I have a SQL database administrate with Django (web Framework). On this database, items are only update.
In other side, I have a NoSQL database (document-oriented). Sometimes, I need to migrate the SQL Data to NoSQL document forms and insert it on the NoSQL database.

I saw this question: [Migrate data from relational DB to NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832199/migrate-data-from-relational-db-to-nosql)
But the answer does not suit me.

And I saw Django-nonrel can help me to get a connector to a NoSQL database.

In my case, are there tools or any solutions more appropriate than create classes and methods in Python by myself for transform SQL data to NoSQL document?

Comment: I have found no solution. The better way, for me, is to create classes using Django queryset and Django rest serializers.