# Project with Laravel and NOSQL

Tags: laravel, mongodb, search, nosql, real-time

I want to start a project on Laravel and want to go for NOSQL. I need extensive search with this project and was considering Mongodb but I am not sure about search.

Few related questions:
Is there enough support for using NOSQL, incase I get stuck somewhere?
NOSQL is flexible enough for searching parameters?
If I need to import data from previous project to NoSQL will it be a challenge?
What about realtime time, does NOSQL supports realtime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends upon on your requirements. Yeah i faced so many challengers when I used mongodb.

Comment: 1) `If I need to import data from previous project to NoSQL will it be a challenge?` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17833456/9471283) 2) `Is there enough support for using NOSQL` there is but you need to learn mongo first, for searching purpose you can use elasticsearch or apache solr,`NOSQL is flexible enough for searching parameters` I would say yes enough  `does NOSQL supports realtime?` I don't understand what you mean to say by realtime here

Comment: @AtifMahmood as mentioned my project needs extensive search.

Comment: @bhucho thanks. it is really helpful. I will look into it and real-time database like firebase and firestore .

Comment: as query is very difficult in mongodb so not prefer mongodb in your case.

Comment: @AtifMahmood nothing like that it depends upon person there are no joins so people get confusd calling it difficult

Comment: @bhucho yeah right.